# Помогите разобраться с php

Tags: php

Такая задача - Человек вводит в форме номера телефонов, через пробел. 8925505050  8918123124 (цифры любые и любое количество)

```
<p>Ваши номера: <input type="text" name="number" /></p>
```

Я принимаю данные

```
$a = explode(" ", $_POST['number']);
```

и загоняю их в массив? Затем мне надо раскидать полученные номера по операторам. Я могу это сделать через if

```
if($a[0] =8925505050)
{ echo "Это номера Мегафона"}
```

Так вот как мне это сделать?

p.s. Проблема в том , давая ключ из массива `$a[0]` я могу привязать иф только к нему. а если там будет другой номер, то это не сработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для российских операторов:

```
$operator_arr = array();
foreach($a as $number){
  $operator = substr($a[0],1,3);
  switch($operator){
    case '916':
    case '910':
    case '915':
    case '917':
      $operator = 'mts';
    break;
    case '926':
    case '925':
      $operator = 'megafon';
    break;
    default:
      $operator = 'unknown';
  }

if(!isset($operator_arr[$operator])){
  $operator_arr[$operator] = array();
}
$operator_arr[$operator][] = $number;
}
```

Вот как-то так и работает.

Comment: А что выводить?

Comment: $a = explode(" ", $_POST['number']);
$operator_arr = array();
foreach($a as $number){
  $operator = substr($a[0],1,3);
  switch($operator){
    case '916':
    case '910':
    case '915':
    case '917':
    $operator = 'mts';
    break;
    case '926':
    case '925':
    $operator = 'megafon';
    break;
    default:
      $operator = 'unknown';
  }

if(!isset($operator_arr[$operator])){
  $operator_arr[$operator] = array();
}
$operator_arr[$operator][] = $number;
}

Comment: $operator_arr имеет вид

    оператор
      номер1
      номер2
      номер3
    оператор2
      номер1
      номер2
      номер3

Выведите его при помощи print_r - посмотрите сами.

Дальше - в зависимости от того как надо представить, либо цикл, либо implode

Comment: Чего-то не все догоняю. $operator = substr($a[0],1,3); вот мы говорим, чтобы он не трогал 8 в начале номера ? А брал цифры от одного 1-3?

Comment: Именно так. Потому что именно эти цифры задают оператора в России.
Если речь про международный формат телефонов, там все намного хуже и сложнее. Например, есть страны с кодом страны в несколько цифр или код оператора больше 3

Answer (score 3):

Наоборот, сначала надо удалить пробелы и привести к каноническому виду, а затем взять префикс оператора

```
Канонический вид: +<код страны><код города/оператора><номер телефона>
Пример: +79130000000
Номера вида 89130000000 надо тоже привести к каноническому
Использовать номера в одном формате удобнее - меньше всяких IF

Затем взять подстроку с 2го по 4ой символы: 913 (нумерация начинается с 0)

Затем по таблице префиксов определить код оператора связи
* Если 913 то МТС
* Если 925 то Мегафон
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $number Номер телефона
 * @return null|string Имя оператора или null если не найден
 */
function findOperatorByNumber($number) {
    // в $number могут быть не только пробелы, но и другие символы
    // важны только начальные +7 и цифры
    $numberCanonical = preg_replace('/[^\d\+]/', '', $number); // удалит всё кроме пробелов и +
    // если номер имеет вид 89130000000
    if (11 == strlen($numberCanonical ) && '8' == $numberCanonical[0]) {
        // сделать +79130000000
        $numberCanonical = '+7'.substr($numberCanonical, 1, 11);
    }
    // проверить итоговый формат
    if (!preg_match('/\+\d{11}/', $numberCanonical)) {
        echo 'Номер телефона "' . $number . '" указан неверно, используйте такой формат: +<код страны><код оператора><номер телефона>.   Пример: +7 913 00000000';
        return null;
    }

    $prefix = substr($numberCanonical, 2, 3);

    // а вот тут простор для творчества - хоть из базы, хоть из файла, хоть простым switch ищем оператора
    $operators = array(
        array('prefix' => '913', 'name' => 'МТС', /* и другие полезные сведения об операторе */),
        array('prefix' => '925', 'name' => 'Мегафон', /* и другие полезные сведения об операторе */),
        // и так далее
    );
    $operator = null;
    foreach($operators as $op) {
        if ($prefix == $op['prefix']) {
            $operator = $op;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (false!==$operator) {
        return $operator['name'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// index.php?number=8925505050%208135505050
$numbers = !empty($_GET['number']) ? explode(' ', $_GET['number']) : array();
foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $operatorName = findOperatorByNumber($number);
    echo $number, ': ', (!is_null($operatorName) ? $operatorName : 'не определён'); 
}
```

Comment: я бы ключем сделал префикс, а операторов ссылками типа

    $operators=array('CОТКОМ'=>array('тут мета оператора');
    $prefixes=array('555'=>'СОТКОМ'],'556'=>'СОТКОМ','557'=>'КОМСОТ');

    foreach ($prefixes as $key=>$name) {$prefixes[$key]=&$operators[$name];}

ну и понятно что на самом деле надо из базы, но в базе тот-же принцип - ключ - префикс. и второй ключ - имя, id делать там нет смысла.

Answer (score -2):

циклом пройдитесь по массиву и проверяйте значение.

```
for ($a as $b) {
   if ($b == 8925505050) echo $b . ' - это номер Мегафона<br>';
   elseif ($b == 8918123124) echo $b . ' - это номер другого оператора<br>';
   // и так далее
}
```