# Помогите разобраться с Php массивами

Tags: массивы, php

**В форму вводятся в столбик номера телефонов**

```
89256378145
89896377767
89166376568
89136375481
```

**Я их принимаю**  И вывожу

```
<?php

$a = explode ("\r\n", $_POST["tel"]);
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
echo '<p>значение - '.$value.' , а  ключ (индекс) '.$key.'</p>' ;

}
?>
```

**В ответ я получаю :**

```
значение - 89256378145 , а ключ (индекс) 0

значение - 89896377767 , а ключ (индекс) 1

значение - 89166376568 , а ключ (индекс) 2

значение - 89136375481 , а ключ (индекс) 3
```

**Теперь мне нужно достать префикс сот. оператора.**
Для этого я в код дописываю $op  = substr($a[0],1,3);

```
<?php

$a = explode ("\r\n", $_POST["tel"]);

foreach ($a as $key => $value ) {
$op = substr($a[0],1,3); 
echo $op;
}

?>
```

**В ответ я получаю :**
    925925925925

То есть, пхп берет первое значение из массива, забирает у него эти три цифры и циклит? Как мне получить все префиксы в таком виде:

```
значение - 925 , а ключ (индекс) 0

значение - 989 , а ключ (индекс) 1

значение - 916 , а ключ (индекс) 2

значение - 913 , а ключ (индекс) 3
```

Помогите я новичок в программировании. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы уже неделю мучаете свои телефоны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так Вы сами написали брать только первые цыфры!

```
$op = substr(**$a[0]**,1,3);
```

Пробуй так:

```
$a = explode ("\r\n", $_POST["tel"]);
$op = array();

foreach ($a as $key => $value ) {
$op = substr($value,1,3); 
echo $op;
}
```

Comment: Да сработало!

Comment: @myvzar, неправильный у вас ответ.
@shatoidil, зря вы его приняли.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы берете значение первого элемента массива:

```
$op = substr($a[0],1,3);
```

А вам нужно каждого:

```
$op = substr($value,1,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот нужный вам код

```
<?php
$a = explode("\n", $_POST["tel"]); // не \r\n, а \n, потому что

$op = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $value = trim($value); // чтобы \r отрезать если вдруг
    // и я бы порекомендовал воспользоваться функцией приведения номеров к одному виду, как вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/325390#325407

    // не $op = ..., а $op[] = ... - скобки квадратные - в данном случае - чтобы установить значение в массив $op, а иначе $op просто переопределяется и получается не массив, а скаляр
    $op[$key] = substr($value,1,3); 

    // после фразы нужно выводить разделитель строк, иначе символы слипаются в одну строку
    //    \n - если через консоль выводите
    //    <br/> - если через web
    echo "значение - {$op[$key]} , а ключ (индекс) {$key}<br/>\n";
}
```

?>

Comment: проверка

    > var_export($a);
    array (
      0 => '89256378145',
      1 => '89896377767',
      2 => '89166376568',
      3 => '89136375481',
    )

    > var_export($op);
    array (
      0 => '925',
      1 => '989',
      2 => '916',
      3 => '913',
    )

Comment: А зачем делать op массивом? Он же прям в этом цикле и выводит эту переменную. Можно вообще без нее обойтись, сделать сразу:

echo substr($value, 1, 3);

И вы опять делаете ту же ошибку, которую автор просит исправить, записываете первый элемент массива в каждую ячейку нового массива:

$op[$key] = substr($a[0],1,3);

Comment: проглядел про $a[0]. исправил.

Comment: >>> А зачем делать op массивом?
да он уже неделю пытается этот массив получить, да всё не с той стороны заходит на посадку :)